# How to set current date in active month using Pabo Calendar?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, calendar, desktop-application

I want to show the current date in Pabo calendar but there is only a read-only property.

How can I set the current date?

```
namespace Pabo.Calendar
{
    [DefaultEvent("MonthChanged")]
    [DefaultProperty("Name")]
    [Designer(typeof(MonthCalendarDesigner))]
    [ToolboxBitmap(typeof(MonthCalendar), "Pabo.Calendar.MonthCalendar.bmp")]
    [ToolboxItem(true)]
    public class MonthCalendar : Control
    {
        public WeekCallBack WeeknumberCallBack;

        public MonthCalendar();

        [Category("Behavior")]
        [Description("")]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
        public ActiveMonth ActiveMonth { get; }
        [Category("Behavior")]
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        [Description("First day of week.")]
        [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]
        [TypeConverter(typeof(FirstDayOfWeekConverter))]
        public int FirstDayOfWeek { get; set; }

    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with the `Pabo.Calendar` control but it looks like you can just update the `Month` or `Year` properties of the object that is returned from the `ActiveMonth` property. Something like this should work:

```
// This code example assumes you have an instance of the 
// MonthCalendar object that is called `myMonthCalendar`.
var today = DateTime.Today;
myMonthCalendar.ActiveMonth.Year = today.Year;
myMonthCalendar.ActiveMonth.Month = today.Month;
```

The above code reads the value from the `ActiveMonth` property (which is an instance of the `ActiveMonth` class, which in turn contains two properties `Year` and `Month`). Next it will set the `Year` and `Month` properties to the desired values. A more verbose version of the code above would be:

```
// This code example assumes you have an instance of the 
// MonthCalendar object that is called `myMonthCalendar`.
var today = DateTime.Today;
var activeMonth = myMonthCalendar.ActiveMonth; // Here we only read the ActiveMonth property.
activeMonth.Year = today.Year; // Here we update or set the Year value
activeMonth.Month = today.Month; // Here we update or set the Month value
```

Comment: but I am unable to set the date in pabo calendar property by default it read only {get;}

Comment: by the way thanks so much for your response Maurits van Beusekom

Comment: in this case you are not setting the `ActiveMonth` property, you are reading it's value and then update or change it's `Year` and `Month` properties.

Comment: okay Sir, My issue has been resolved but I don't know how is it happened :)

Comment: Did you follow my suggestion? Would you like me to explain more detailed? B.t.w. if my answer helped you to solve the problem, I would appreciate it if you mark it as "Accepted answer" (by clicking on the checkmark symbol). This helps other users to identify the solution and I get rewarded some stackoverflow points which helps my reputation.